# How to use notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon) in latest Android SDK update?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to use `setSmallIcon(Icon.createWithBitmap())` to create small icon for my notification but the constructor `NotificationCompat.Builder(context)` is deprecated now and the latest constructor `NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)` doesn't contain this method which accepts `icon` as parameter. How can I use icon object in latest notification builder?

```
val channelId =
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            { createNotificationChannel("111", "Speed Monitor Service") } else { "" }

        val remoteView = RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.notification)
        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background) //this method only accepts int not Icon
            .setCustomContentView(remoteView)
            .build()

        startForeground(1, notification)
```

Comment: What error do you get if you pass an Icon and how are you creating that Icon ?

Comment: I got it. I was using NotificationCompat.Builder instead of Notification.Builder.

Comment: Yes I checked it too NotificationCompat.Builder doesn't have setSmallIcon() with an Icon as a parameter. I thought you weren't able to find and use it under Notification.Builder class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Notification.Builder.setSmallIcon](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setSmallIcon(int)) is what you need to use. If you need to utilize older API levels, you can use `NotificationCompat.Builder`.

This method has several overrides depending on the resource you would like to use, if you need to use a runtime image, and not a resource bundled in the application, you can leverage the [Icon](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Icon.html) class and the method `Notification.Builder.setSmallIcon(Icon icon)`.

Comment: As for API level 26 (Oreo) and above NotificationChannel is the way to go. https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

Comment: That is incorrect. Take a look at the api for NotificationChannel: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel There are no methods for setting an icon for notifications on the channel.

Comment: No, NotificationChannel and Notification.Builder are two different things. I meant that Android O and above requires a notification channel to be set using NotificationManager. You will still use Notification.Builder or NotificationCompat.Builder. It was just a side note.                                            
See the sendNotification() function in the following google samples https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/Geofencing/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/geofencing/GeofenceTransitionsJobIntentService.java

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Your first comment seemed to imply that the correct answer to the question was to set the icon on the channel, not the builder. You are correct, in 26 and above, you will want to leverage notification channels.

Comment: @ElliWhite i am familiar of this function but I can't use it. I don't want to select a resource from drawable. Rather, I am creating bitmap at runtime and i want that to appear as small icon in status bar

Comment: @HashirSarwar I've updated my question to provide a way to do what you've asked. I would recommend reading the documentation, as the method you need is right alongside the one I linked to in my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague let me clear it up for you. `Notification.Builder(context)` (which is deprecated) and `Notification.Builder(context, channelId)` are two constructors of the same class `Notification.Builder`. The class itself is not deprecated.

> Notification.Builder(context, channelId) doesn't contain this method
>   which accepts icon as parameter

The above statement is wrong (wrong as in technically wrong). Using either of the constructors doesn't imply you are using two different classes. There is only one class here `Notification.Builder`and it does contains the function `setSmallIcon(Icon icon)` as you can see here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setSmallIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Icon)

In other words `setSmallIcon(Icon icon)` has to be there. The reason you are not seeing this function can be different. Show the code for further clearance.

Comment: I have double checked. setSmallIcon(Icon icon) method is not present in the latest constructor of the Notification.Builder class. I have updated my question with code. Thanks

Comment: You might have to change a bit of wordings in your sentences. Methods are not present inside a constructor but present inside a class. Constructor is itself a method. What you are saying implies that other methods are inside the constructor method, which is wrong to say.

Comment: I am sorry. I meant the method setSmallIcon(Icon icon) is not present FOR the latest constructor. Is there something I am doing wrong? Or its actually not present?

Comment: lol, Pardon me not here to correct your wordings but I think it better to clear things. Functions are not present FOR any constructors they are just present right there inside a class. Using any constructor (which is also a method inside a class like setSmallIcon() ) doesn't mean that other methods will be available or unavailable. I don't know what is happening in your IDE or compiler but check my latest comment under your question. Thanks